# Grey out several labels of same css class at once

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to grey out several labels of the same CSS class at once? In my current code, I grey out every label via its id but it would be much easier to have a way to grey out several labels at once.

Code snippet of current version:

```
<label id="label1" class="my-label">Label1</label><br>
<label id="label2" class="my-label">Label2</label><br>
<label id="label3" class="my-label">Label3</label>
```

Angular controller:

```
if(someAction) {
 $('#label1').css("color", "#1d1d1b");
 $('#label2').css("color", "#1d1d1b");
 $('#label3').css("color", "#1d1d1b");
}
```

Comment: If you want to gray all label at once use common class but separate then you have to use id.

Comment: do you want angular js way?

Comment: Yeah, the AngularJS way would be interesting, too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector for classes is

```
 $(".my-label").css('color', '#1d1d1b');
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried like:

```
if(someAction) {
 $('.my-label').css("color", "#1d1d1b");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you wrap your labels in some wrapper element like this:

```
<div class="label-wrapper">
    <label id="label1" class="my-label">Label1</label><br>
    <label id="label2" class="my-label">Label2</label><br>
    <label id="label3" class="my-label">Label3</label>
</div>
```

Add the following to your css file:

```
.grayed-out .my-label {
    color: #1d1d1b;
}
```

And in your controller:

```
if(someAction) {
    $('.label-wrapper').addClass('grayed-out');
}
```

This way, you only apply/toggle class on a single element,
and let the css do the styling for you

Comment: Will try it out, thank you. Although the other two previous answers work fine, too.